# Turn showdow off for one date in document

Tags: date, datetime2

**MRE**:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[showdow,en-GB]{datetime2}

% Document
\begin{document}
    % Turn off showdow
    \DTMlangsetup{ord=raise,showyear=true,showdow=false}
    % Format a date
    \DTMdate{2019-01-01}

    % Turn showdow back on
    \DTMlangsetup{ord=raise,showyear=true,showdow=true}
    % Format the same date
    \DTMdate{2019-01-01}
\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

> 1<sup>st</sup> January 2019
>
> Tuesday 1<sup>st</sup> January 2019

**Actual output:**

> Tuesday 1<sup>st</sup> January 2019
>
> Tuesday 1<sup>st</sup> January 2019

Screnshot:

[image: Screenshot of actual output]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must use `\DTMsetup`

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[showdow,en-GB,en-AU]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup{ord=raise,showyear=true,showdow=true}

% Document
\begin{document}
    % Turn off showdow
    \DTMsetup{showdow=false}
    % Format a date
    \DTMdate{2019-01-01}

    % Turn showdow back on
    \DTMsetup{showdow=true}
    % Format the same date
    \DTMdate{2019-01-01}
\end{document}
```

Per p. 66 of the official manual:

[image: Docs]